# What is the difference between declaring variables within the derived type vs. within subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: oop, module, fortran, derived-types

When setting up a module, what is the difference between defining variables within the derived type definition, versus within a subroutine for that module? Specifically I will need to 'pass' data from one module to another. For example `MathStuffModule` adds some numbers within a subroutine, and then `PrintStuffModule` prints those numbers (actual problem is much more complex, but I'm still trying to understand the basics).

For example in the code below, what is the difference between the variable "answer" and "AddThis" as far as how they each relate to the module, how/if they can be called outside of the module (and say passed to a PrintStuffModule), and calling/defining the variables within the actual program?

```
        module MathStuffModule

        type MathStuffType
            integer :: answer
        contains
            procedure :: mathstuff1
        end type MathStuffType

        contains 
          subroutine mathstuff1(m,AddThis,number)
          class(MathStuffType) :: m
          real :: AddThis,number,answer
          m%answer = number + AddThis
          end subroutine mathstuff1

        end module MathStuffModule
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please note that your code is *not* Fortran 90 but at least Fortran 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, I'm not 100% sure what OP is asking about.

Module entities are available within any scope that includes a `use` statement; in this example it would be `use mathstuffmodule`.

This business of one scope being able to manipulate entities defined in another scope is called *use-association*, it's all about associating entities in (possibly complex and long) programs by clever use of `use` statements.

Optionally a `use` statement can restrict the module entities associated, by using an `only` clause, or it can rename module entities so they are known by a different name in the using scope.

To keep things simple think only, at this stage, of program's using modules. If a program includes a `use` statement, then any module entities are in scope whenever any program entity is in scope.  Program entities (and entities use-associated into a program) are typically in scope throughout the program's execution, but may get masked in sub-scopes.

I wouldn't call `answer` a variable, I'd call it a member of the derived type `mathstufftype`.  If an entity of that type is declared in a program scope, then the member can be accessed by a term something like `entity%answer`.

I wouldn't call `addthis` a variable either, it's a dummy argument name for the routine `mathstuff1`.  It would be an error to use the name `addthis` outside the routine to refer to that argument.  (It would be possible to declare a variable called `addthis` in another scope, if you want to confuse matters.)

In isolation, there is nothing called `answer` nor anything called `addthis` which can be `use`d by a client of the module and manipulated like a variable.

It's probably also not helpful to think of passing data between modules.  If a program uses two modules, then it has access to any entities defined in either, and can use, say, a variable defined in one module as a parameter to a routine defined in the other.  It's also possible for module A to `use` module B; then (a) code in B can manipulate entities use-associated from A and (b) any other module (or program) which `use`s B also gets (transitively) access to the entities in A.

Comment: It seems my basic understanding of how a module works was off, which is likely why the question was a bit confusing.  Thank you for the clarification!